# How to convert Face Duplication to a permanent single/many objects?

Tags: python, modifiers, blender-internal-render-engine

I want to convert a face duplicated object into a permanent object.

For example: If I have a Plane with 100 faces and each face is duplicated by an object (let say: a cylinder), then the converted Plane should create 100 individual cylinders or a single object with 100 cylinders.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: +Carlo - Yes. That is all what I wanted.

Comment: Good! I'll mark as duplicated of that question.